# Does the YouTube Upload Widget uses Flash or HTML5

Tags: html, flash, youtube, youtube-data-api

Reading [its documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget) one might think that it uses HTML5 especially if focusing on this text:

> The widget uses HTML5's postMessage support to send messages back to
>   your website regarding videos uploaded via the widget.

In addition, when I read the "Note" where it says it `loads the same JavaScript file as the IFrame Player API`, I thought it really does use HTML5 as the [IFrame player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) do.

However, when I try the widget on a mobile device I was presented with a "You need to upgrade your Adobe Flash Player..." error. Unfortunately, both iPhone and Android devices do not support it.

So the question is, does the widget use a Adobe Flash or HTML5. If the latter, can it be controlled via settings that was not defined in the doc?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your question, the [Youtube Upload Widget](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget) uses

> HTML5's postMessage support to send messages back to your website regarding videos uploaded via the widget.

So yes it's using HTML5 for this task, but for the video capturing part, the widget uses flash and that's why in mobile or even in desktop browser with flash player disabled, you will get the message that invite you to install flash player.

For the widget parameters, there is nothing, in my knowledge at least, to force it to load a HTML5 version which, I think, didn't exist yet now.

Hope that can help.